# i want to run javascript file in my php file with exec() function, but it came up with error message , how can i fix it?

Tags: javascript, php

I am writing some PHP code, I tried to run JS in my php with exec() function, but after I run on web browser JS came out with error, what should I do to fix this problem?

***php***

```
//after run below code, Javascript runtime error message shown
$response = exec("D:\xampp\htdocs\lazada.js");
echo $response;
```

I expected the JS could be run successfully after i run my php code on web browser

Comment: Would you mind sharing the error?

Comment: .js files aren't executable, you need something like `exec("node D:\xampp\htdocs\lazada.js");`

Comment: Can you share the purpose of the .js ? If it is to be render in the browser then rather use $jsContent = file_get_contens('<JS_PATH>') and echo that output in the HMTL <script><?php echo $jsContent?></script>

Answer (score 0):

Load the file content in the variable and print that variable in the HTML.

```
<?php $jsContent = file_get_contents("D:\xampp\htdocs\lazada.js");?>
<script><?php echo $jsContent;?></script>
```